# How to have a blogspot blog in my domain?

Tags: blog, blogger

I have a blog at `http://example.blogspot.com`. How can I have this blog and all old posts, comments and templates in my own domain like `http://example.com/`?

Which specifications this domain must have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All covered in the [blogger documentation](http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55373).