# 301 redirect blogspot to an existing domain?

Tags: seo, redirects, blog, domains

Is it possible to redirect a blogspot site to an existing URL?

Note that I don't want to buy a new domain and tell blogspot to use that, eg as per this question: [How to have a blogspot blog in my domain?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/how-to-have-a-blogspot-blog-in-my-domain).

Instead I am trying to 301 redirect to an existing website in order to combine the website and the blog in one place.  So it needs to be:

```
301 example.blogspot.com/post to example.com/blog/post
```

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation referenced at the question you linked to:

> You can use this feature with domains
>   (e.g. example.com) or subdomains (e.g.
>   blog.example.com). However, you cannot
>   specify subdirectories (e.g.
>   example.com/blog/) or wildcards (e.g.
>   *.example.com).

[How do I use a custom domain name on my blog?](http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55373)

Whether Blogger/Blogspot implements a redirect is really up to Google, as Google is effectively your hosting provider when you use that blogging platform.

I'd assume changing your Blogger blog settings to point to the *subdomain* at your domain (*not* a subdirectory) would create a 301 redirect, as Google tends to be pretty good about implementing best practices... but keep in mind, you can't use a subdirectory unless you want to proxy requests to the subdirectory on your main domain through to the server where your blog resides.

**Updated:**

> I need a way to tell blogspot to 301
>   from each post made on blogspot to the
>   identical post made on the existing
>   domain.

If that is the case, try this:

1. Set up a DNS record for blogspot.example.com to point to Blogspot (per the instructions from that article)
2. Complete the blogspot blog transfer (per that article)
3. Once the transfer is complete (i.e. example.blogspot.com redirects to blogspot.example.com) change the DNS record for blogspot.example.com to point to your server at example.com
4. Assuming Blogspot continues pushing traffic to your blogspot.example.com subdomain (which it may or may not) you can set up a redirect from blogspot.example.com/* to example.com/blog/*

Comment: I'm not sure that answers the question.  I don't want to use blogspot anymore.  Instead I would be taking all old blogspot posts, and making an identical one on the existing domain.  I need a way to tell blogspot to 301 from each post made on blogspot to the identical post made on the existing domain.