# To move a BlogSpot blog to a custom domain with new hosting, can I first enable the custom doman on BlogSpot and then change the CNAME?

Tags: seo, wordpress, blogger, site-move

I need to move my blog say example.blogspot.com to example.com and custom service provider say Hostgator.
I want to do this migration without impacting the SEO.

What I am thinking of 
1. Using the link below I just change pointing of example.blogspot.com to example.com.
https://www.shoutmeloud.com/setup-blogspot-custom-domain.html

2. After a week when all my pages are migrated from 
   example.blogspot.com to example.com, I will revert the settings of cname and now exmaple.com starts pointing to HostGator

Is this approach ok or a better solution is there?

Comment: See also: [301 redirect blogspot to an existing domain?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7227/301-redirect-blogspot-to-an-existing-domain)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks, Its seems i was on right direction. you can post answer so that i can choose ur ans as best