# Redirecting from blogger to custom domain

Tags: domains, blogger, 302-redirect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to have a blogspot blog in my domain?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/how-to-have-a-blogspot-blog-in-my-domain)

i have a blog from blogger named as [www.myclipta.blogspot.com](http://myclipta.blogspot.com). i am updating regulary. Then i bought a custom domain with [myclipta.com](http://myclipta.com). Now i want to redirect from blogger domain to my custom domain.

i don't know how to do this . i heard that to set dns name servers and CNAME..But i am not able to do this..

can any one can guide me please..

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](http://tendou86.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-redirect-blogger-blogspot-into.html) might be the solution to your needs

Comment: i will try and let u know after my blog redirection.Thanks.