# Moving a Blogspot blog to a new domain?

Tags: domains, godaddy, blogger

I have a blog with blogger.com. And I wanted to move it to a domain name now. i have purchased a domain name with go daddy. I have little technical know-how, so would appreciate any help with regards to moving my blog to a domain name. Help, please? 
Like, I want to move all my contents to a domain name.

Comment: @Su' already gave you the best answer, I must also add that setting up a domain from GoDaddy for Blogger is very easy and you don't need any technical knowledge.

Comment: Do you want to continue to use blogger to edit your blog? If you do then the wget answer below won't help you, but I wanted to check before I commented on that answer.

Comment: If the answer is yes, then your question is a duplicate of this one: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/how-to-have-a-blogspot-blog-in-my-domain?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

There are [instructions](http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/static.py?hl=en&ts=1233381&page=ts.cs) for having your blog display at a custom domain, but you should note that this doesn't *move* anything in a literal sense, eg. no files will be created at a hosting account, etc. (This is probably what you're actually after, but if not be sure to clarify your question.)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the command line program call wget.  It's quick and easy for recursively getting websites.

```
wget -r http://the_url_to_your_home_page
```

Comment: Can you give more details about the function and a link will be great to.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/